# datetimepicker don't want my php-variable

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have a big problem which really confused me the last five hours.

I use datetimepicker.

```
<?php
$tabname = "frequency";
$datumstart = "'#datumstart".$tabname."'";
?>
<script type ="text/javascript">
$(function(){$(<?php echo $datumstart; ?>).datetimepicker();
</script>
<input type="text" name="datumstart<?php echo $tabname; ?/>
```

I want to get the value of the input-field with

```
$(function load() {
var datumstart = $(<? php echo $datumstart; ?>).val(); });
```

So everytime I want to run the file with this line

```
var datumstart = $(<? php echo $datumstart; ?>).val(); });
```

the alert-output of var datumstart is blank.

But with this

```
var datumstart = $('#datumstartfrequency').val(); });
```

I get the value!

What can be wrong?

Comment: Always look at the view source! Never look at the php code to debug JavaScript! What does the rendered code look like?

Comment: Does `<input type="text" name="datumstart<?php echo $tabname; ?/>` have an `id` of `datumstartfrequency`? What you posted has only a `name` attribute, without an `id` attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing apostrophes:

```
$('<?php echo $datumstart; ?>')
```

Comment: better yet, `echo json_encode($datumstart)`, which will add the quotes for you, and make sure you're producing syntactically valid JS to boot.

Comment: With the apostrophes the page don't load because there are already apostrophes ...  
$datumstart = "'#datumstartfrequency'";